# Issue with binding data from Modal Dialog to another area of web app

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I've been searching around for a solution to a problem, which I believe should be relatively easy to solve - that being the use of Angular.js's two-way databinding

I have a modal dialog (using the Angular ui-bootstrap code for modal dialog) from which I want to take inputted text and output to the main application page, I've got a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/piFB2GfpsZVXsiqOHGGg?p=preview) (it works with data-binding as I can see the input value in the modal dialog), however i'm wanting to take that value and bind it to the section under Projects

my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add Project</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Project Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
            {{name}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        In Modal: {{ name }}
        </script>

        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Add Project</button>
    </div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="table-responsive" ng-model="name">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Project</th>
                                    <th>Badges</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$scope.name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
        </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

my javascript

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.name = "";

    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                projName: function () {
                    return $scope.name;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (pName) {
            $scope.name = pName;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, projName) {

    $scope.name = projName;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.name);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by **under Projects**?

Comment: First of there is difference in code from plunker and what you have posted here and if you alert ``$scope.name``  before assigning  ``projName``  to it in ``ModalInstanceCtrl`` then what result you are getting ?? I think if you comment ``$scope.name = projName;`` then it will work.

Comment: to show the text value from the modal under the table heading of Projects

Comment: @GhostCore Your plunkr sample seems working just fine. It gives the expected result.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your patience on this, I've updated with question with the correct code and Plunker (still trying to get my head around how to use that properly)

Comment: Where the table entry Project / Badge is, I'm wanting to take the text entered in the modal dialog and interpolate it into the area underneath Project

Answer (score 1):

As the main application page is operated by ModalDemoCtrl controller and model is operated by ModalInstanceCtrl controller, so they can't use the scope variable of each other, these controllers have no relationship.

There is the only way to pass ModalDemoCtrl scope variable data to ModalInstanceCtrl, using resolve method of $model service, as you did.

```
resolve:{items: function () {return $scope.items;}
```

and ModalInstanceCtrl scope data to ModalDemoCtrl using $modalInstance.close(modeldata), which you did.

so if you want to pass the modal input to main application. use it as below ...

### In ModalInstanceCtrl

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.name);
  };
```

### In ModalDemoCtrl

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (nameFromModal) {
      $scope.name = nameFromModal;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the help, unfortunately i'm still not getting any success :( http://plnkr.co/edit/2RmthZ2bENaIUnAP2gOk?p=preview < Updated plunker